# How to get Wireshark to monitor a specific IP in the background

Tags: networking, wireshark, packet-analyzer

I have got Wireshark installed and I am wanting to monitor the traffic to and from a specific IP address, so what would be really useful would be if I could get Wireshark to start by itself on startup and then start capturing packets on `eth0` which are either from or to that specific IP address. It would also then be very useful for it to save the captured packets automatically that match these specifications to a directory that I would specify. I know that such a thing, or at least something similar, could be done, but I just do not know the technical detail of exactly how I would get it to work, so that is really why I am asking about it here.

Even if I would not be able to get it to startup in the background on startup and start doing this by itself without launching any GUI, at least a way so that I could get it to filter and automatically save specific packets would be good (even if I would need to manually start Wireshark).

**Information Update:**

The current solution provided does not seem to be working, this is now the new contents of my `/etc/network/interfaces` file:

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
post-up tcpdump -i eth0 host 80.177.214.176 -w '/home/arthur-dent/tcpdumpLog/eth0-%F-%H-%M-%S.bin' -G 600 &
```

So is this how it should look, is a restart required, or any command to be executed?

---

**OS Information:**

```
Description:    Ubuntu 14.10
Release:    14.10
```

**Package Information:**

```
wireshark:
  Installed: 1.12.1+g01b65bf-2~ubuntu14.10.3
  Candidate: 1.12.1+g01b65bf-2~ubuntu14.10.3
  Version table:
 *** 1.12.1+g01b65bf-2~ubuntu14.10.3 0
        500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic-updates/universe amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic-security/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1.12.0+git+4fab41a1-1 0
        500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic/universe amd64 Packages
```

Comment: It is called tcpdump

Comment: Keep in mind that the startup stuff is not run by you, it is run by root. Therefore "~" is meaningless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The suggestion is to use tcpdump to do the actual packet capturing and saving. You can still use wireshark to view the packets in detail later on.

For example (where I am using a local IP address, just for the example):

```
sudo tcpdump -i eth0 host 192.168.111.190 -w 'eth0-%F-%H-%M-%S.bin' -G 600
```

will capture all traffic to/from 192.168.111.190 and save the entire packet to a file. To prevent huge files, and to make later investigation easier, the file name is changed every 10 minutes, with the file name containing the date and time as an identifier. Example:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root      169739 Apr 16 16:11 tcpdump/075/eth0-2015-04-16-16-01-02.bin
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root       60191 Apr 16 16:21 tcpdump/075/eth0-2015-04-16-16-11-02.bin
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root      177895 Apr 16 16:31 tcpdump/075/eth0-2015-04-16-16-21-02.bin
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root      134816 Apr 16 16:41 tcpdump/075/eth0-2015-04-16-16-31-02.bin
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root      660839 Apr 16 16:51 tcpdump/075/eth0-2015-04-16-16-41-02.bin
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root      678867 Apr 16 17:00 tcpdump/075/eth0-2015-04-16-16-51-02.bin
```

Now, say I had an interesting `/var/log/kern.log` entry, that I wanted to investigate in detail at the packet level. I would open wireshark and use `file` then `open` and open the appropriate file based on the log entry timestamp.

Alternatively, you could use the `-C` option instead of `-G` to rotate the output files based on file size instead of by time. See the [tcpdump man](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man8/tcpdump.8.html) page for more details.

Now, to automate starting this command on boot, you could add it to `/etc/rc.local`, as mentioned in the comments, however that might be prone to a race condition between rc.local and the interface not being up in time, resulting in the following entry in `/var/log/syslog` (where it did not work 1 out of 3 times):

```
Apr 22 12:06:45 desk-ss rc.local[679]: tcpdump: listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
Apr 22 13:30:47 desk-ss rc.local[674]: tcpdump: eth0: That device is not up
Apr 22 13:33:20 desk-ss rc.local[665]: tcpdump: listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
```

So consider adding a delay, or adding it as a post-up addition to the `/etc/network/interfaces` file. First, the delay method the below line is added to `/etc/rc.local`:

```
sleep 20; tcpdump -i eth0 host 192.168.111.1 -w '/home/doug/eth0-%F-%H-%M-%S.bin' -G 600 &
```

Second, the post-up method, here is the `/etc/network/interfaces` file:

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
post-up tcpdump -i eth0 host 192.168.111.1 -w '/home/doug/eth0-%F-%H-%M-%S.bin' -G 600 &
```

For reference, here is the original `/etc/network/interfaces` file:

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

Comment: What is this bit of the command about `-w 'eth0-%F-%H-%M-%S.bin'`? And basically do I need to change anything with that? Is that the file it will log to or...?

Comment: `-w' means to write the raw packet capture to a file. The rest defines the file name, as per [strftime format](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man3/strftime.3.html). see also my example file names.

Comment: So how to I specify the location of the log files? Or where do I find them on my system if I do not specify them?

Comment: Also about starting up on startup, I am pretty sure that you would do that by getting it to execute the command in `rc.local` by adding the command in before the `exit 0`, as on startup all commands are executed in there as root.

Comment: Startup: I agree, just didn't think about it yet. File location will be whatever you specify. In my example, I ran the command from the tcpdump/075 directory.

Comment: And what is this package that you speak of that I need to install to get it to work?

Comment: And if I wanted to store the logs in my home directory how exactly would you full command look?

Comment: complete write location: see edited answer. Tested on a VM on my system. Required package: It seems to work by default now, it didn't a few years ago. Answer edited.

Comment: So what exactly will the log entries look like if the entire packet is saved to file? Can I not get it so that the packets are saved in a specific location and then I have a log file which logs some information about them, and then tells me where they are located in my system? I just don't want them to be very clustered in the file. Maybe you can show me a few example log entries that you might find in a file with, say, 5 packets?

Comment: I do not understand your application or your previous comments questions. My answer is about saving the raw packets to date and time stamped files for subsequent examination in detail via wireshark. You might want something different. Typically, in my case I am wanting to examine packets related to some log entry from `iptables in /var/log/kern.log` or from something else in `/var/log/auth.log`. However, you could also just post process the packets with tcpdump to get text readable data, or not bother to save the raw packets to begin with, and just get tcpdump to make readable text instead.

Comment: In the `/etc/network/interfaces` file its contents is this `# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback`, so should I just add a line after that that says `sudo tcpdump -i eth0 host 192.168.111.190 -w 'eth0-%F-%H-%M-%S.bin' -G 600`? And if so, then should I also use `sudo`?

Comment: Answer expanded to include `interfaces` file example. No sudo, because it already runs as root.

Comment: This bit `# The primary network interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp` which you have included in your answer is not in my `/etc/network/interfaces` file, should I add it then, or just append the line `tcpdump -i eth0 host 192.168.111.190 -w 'eth0-%F-%H-%M-%S.bin' -G 600`?

Comment: You have to do what is appropriate for your system. I am just providing examples based on my system. If your interface name is `eth0` and if it gets its ip address via dhcp, then you can do exactly what I did. Regardless the command must be related to an interface name and must be part of a `post-up`

Comment: A `post-up`? What is that? So do I just basically put it after what is in my config file?

Comment: see [the man page for interfaces](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man5/interfaces.5.html) search for "post-up"

Comment: Is any command in need of execution after adding that line to `/etc/network/interfaces`? Or a restart, as I have done so, and still nothing is getting logged even though Wireshark is showing me definite activity? Is there anything else that I have to add to that file as well as the line? I have also edited my question to include the contents currently of that file.

Comment: No. Yes. No. You did it incorrectly. Do it the way I showed in my answer. Don't use "~" in the path.

Comment: Ok, I have corrected that, and also updated the information in my question, but it still does not appear to be logging anything, I see in your example that you have two sections, one of which is for `eth0`, do I need to create anything like that for it to work?

Comment: Yes. Currently you have the `post-up` associated with lo. Probably eth0 is not up yet. You can, and should, verify by observing entries in `/var/log/syslog`, similar to the example in my answer.

Comment: Ok, so the output of the command `grep tcpdump /var/log/syslog` as you suggested on the [other question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/616917/how-to-view-var-log-syslog-contents-without-crash/616994), is: `May  1 20:34:06 Bath-Towel networking[577]: tcpdump: eth0: That device is not up`. So what should I do about this?

Comment: Do it properly, and as per my answer. If your situation is different, read man pages and modify accordingly.

Comment: I have noticed that the file is getting called `eth0-%F-%H-%M-%S.bin`, should some of that not be changing to other information and not just having a file saved with that exact name?

Comment: Yes, it should convert just like my examples do. One used to need to install an extra package for it to work properly, but I tested a brand new install with no additional packages and it worked fine, so I edited that out of my answer

Comment: Could you just let me know of the name of the package anyway so that I can check if I have it installed just in case?

Comment: The thing is that I couldn't remember the package name. I always have the meta package `build-essential` installed, which includes the required package. I gave up looking after my fresh install test proved (at least in my case) it works by default now.

Comment: Right, well I have got the `build-essential` package installed, so I don't see what the problem can be.

Comment: Neither do I...

Comment: So if I cannot seem to get this part of it to work, is there a more basic alternative which would make it at least just not overwrite the old file?

Comment: I am only aware of the -C option (already in my answer) as an alternative, albeit file size based instead of time based.