# How to view '/var/log/syslog' contents without crash

Tags: log, crash, syslog

For various reasons it is necessary for me to check the log of my computer in `/var/log/syslog`, but this has become a bit of a problem because I am not actually able to view the logs in that file because every time that I open it (no matter which program I use) it crashes. For instance if I open it in `nano`, `gedit`, `cat`, or even the main log viewing program, I get a crash such as this one because there is just too much data in the file to load:

[image: Main log veiwer GUI crashed]

So really my question is, how can I view `syslog` without the viewer crashing? Am I doing something wrong? Or is there just a better way that everyone use and I am not aware of?

---

### OS Information:

```
Description:    Ubuntu 15.04
Release:    15.04
```

Comment: How many lines are there, do a `wc -l`..how often does it rotate? it might have unusual contents..can you use `less` to read it ?

Comment: Very odd. You should be able to use nano or whatever. For what you want just now, for your other question, try this: `grep tcpdump /var/log/syslog`

Comment: @heemayl: The output of `wc -l /var/log/syslog` command is `1308061 /var/log/syslog`.

Comment: Thats weird..Add the output of `sed -n '/\/var\/log\/syslog/,/^}$/p' /etc/logrotate.d/rsyslog` ....can you read the file using `less` ?

Comment: @heemayl: The output of that command was `sed: can't read /etc/logrotate.d/rsyslo: No such file or directory
`, so do I need to first create that file? And yes it seems that I am able to read the file using `less`, although it is not very useful especially if I am trying to find something specific in that file, or a particular line number, which I am, so this method (although it does not crash) is not very helpful to me either.

Comment: You missed a `g` at last ..the file name is `/etc/logrotate.d/rsyslog`

Comment: @heemayl: Woops! Will try that against then!

Comment: @heemayl: Ok, so the output of that command is: `/var/log/syslog
{
 rotate 7
 daily
 missingok
 notifempty
 delaycompress
 compress
 postrotate
  service rsyslog rotate >/dev/null 2>&1 || true
 endscript
}
`

Comment: Open the file with `less` and check the starting & ending time..

Comment: @heemayl: Start: `May  1 11:37:06`. End: `May  2 13:16:38`. Unless I got something wrong, this information should be accurate.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23367/discussion-between-heemayl-and-paranoid-panda).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**TL;DR :**

The problem was due to the file `var/log/syslog` being very large in size with `kernel` especially `ufw` dumping a lot of `UFW_AUDIT` logs regularly. To solve the problem we need to set the `LOGLEVEL` of `ufw` as `low` in the `ufw` configuration file `/etc/ufw/ufw.conf`:

```
sudo sed -i '/^LOGLEVEL/s/=.*/=low/' /etc/ufw/ufw.conf
```

From `man ufw`:

```
Loglevels above medium generate a lot of logging output, and may 
quickly fill up your disk. Loglevel medium may generate a lot of 
logging output on a busy system.
```

**DETAILS :**

There might be many reasons why the error

```
Stream has outstanding operation
```

is shown. The most common two being the file is too large in size to be read and file has unusual contents that could not be read.

At first we have considered the first cause i.e. file is too big (i will show the steps one by one as we have done it):

- At first we need to check how many lines are there in `/var/log/syslog` and it turned out to be quite unusual:

  ```
  $ wc -l /var/log/syslog
  1308061 /var/log/syslog
  ```
- As the file has 1308061 number of lines which is quite big, we need to check how the `logrorate` is configured for `rsyslog` by:

  ```
  sed -n '/\/var\/log\/syslog/,/^}$/p' /etc/logrotate.d/rsyslog
  ```

This have shown that `/var/log/syslog` will rotate every day with logs older than one week being deleted, which is the default.

- Next we need to check `/var/log/syslog` to see which process is writing most logs to the file using the command:

  ```
  less /var/log/syslog | tr -s ' ' | cut -d' ' -f5 | sort | uniq -c | sort -rn
  ```

This will show us the processes written most lines in the file in a descending order. We found that `kernel` has written to file the highest with the count being very high (1761519). The next is `thermald` with its several processes wrote about 5K times.

- Considering 1kernel1 as the source of this anomaly, we have checked for a pattern in the `/var/log/syslog` that is occurring regularly by:

  ```
  grep "kernel" /var/log/syslog | less
  ```

and found one that was about `UFW AUDIT` and it was very very regularly writing in the log file.

- `ufw` will dump these messages if the `LOGLEVEL` is set as `medium` and more. To find the current value:

  ```
  $ grep -i "^loglevel" /etc/ufw/ufw.conf
  LOGLEVEL=full
  ```

Thats the source of the problem, to get rid of these regular messages it needs to be `LOGLEVEL=low`, it should be sufficient in most cases. From `man ufw`:

```
low    logs all blocked packets not matching the default policy 
(with rate  limiting), as well as  packets  matching  logged rules.
```

Check the `LOGGING` section of `man ufw` to get more idea on `ufw` logging.

Answer (score 6):

Try `less /var/log/syslog`

Press shift-f to go to the end of file and monitor changes like `tail -f /var/log/syslog`

You should see your log file.

There must be some garbage on them or maybe size issues that are preventing the Syslog app to view them. So, rename it and try to open the Syslog app again. You should be able to see your new log file.